# Word Wrap Line Break not working in UILabel only for specific text Strings

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

I have a `UITableViewController` with a custom prototype cell with three labels and one button. The middle label (called `descriptionLabel`) is a multi-line label with Word Wrap as the "Line Breaks" option and 0 lines set in the Attributes inspector.

If I set the `descriptionLabel.text` property assigning a literal `String`, the Word Wrap option works fine, as shown in the following image:

[Cell with Word Wrap working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n41dx.png)

The problem is that the `descriptionLabel`'s text comes from an object. This object is downloaded from a web service and is stored locally, and it's also used to fill all the others labels of the cell.

When I assign the object-property String to the `descriptionLabel`'s text (`cell.descriptionLabel.text = monthlyPaymentType.detail`), however, the Word Wrap is not working, as shown in the image below:

[Cell with Word Wrap NOT working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqNwB.png)

In this case, "cobrado" is one word, but it is being character-wrapped instead of word-wrapped.

It's strange because If I copy the result of `print(monthlyPaymentType.detail)`, paste as a literal String and assign it to `cell.descriptionLabel.text`, the Word Wrap option also **does not** work.

But if I manually type a literal String with exactly the same content of `print(monthlyPaymentType.detail)` and assign it to `cell.descriptionLabel.text`, the Word Wrap option **does** work.

Am I doing anything wrong when configuring the Label? Is it any problem with the stored String in my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the whitespaces in the Strings that come from the server and are stored in the objects are Unicode [Non-Breaking Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (U+00A0). When these Strings are assigned to the `UILabel` `text` property, Non-Breaking Spaces are not considered as word separators.

To solve this problem, I replace the occurrences of U+00A0 characters with common Unicode whitespace (U+0020), using `String`'s method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{00A0}", withString: "\u{0020}")`.